# How to resolve SQLGrammer Exception?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am trying to execute an sql query using hibernate.If I am executing it in the Mysql query browser I am getting the results, but when I am executing as a part of hibernate query, it is giving SQLGrammer exception and then it shows it cannot execute the query. Below is the query code that is throwing exception,

```
StringBuffer queryBuffer = new StringBuffer();
  queryBuffer.append("select region, ");
      queryBuffer.append("ABS( DATEDIFF(:date,endDate) ) as resultDiff ");
      queryBuffer.append("from location  where ");
      queryBuffer.append("employeeId = :id ");
      queryBuffer.append("ORDER BY resultDiff");
      //queryBuffer.append("LIMIT 1");
      arrParamNames = new String[] {"date","id"};
      arrParamValues = new Object[] {date,id};

      lstEmployeedomains=hibernateTemplate.findByNamedParam(queryBuffer.toString(), 
              arrParamNames, arrParamValues);
```

Below is the stack trace,

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could
>   not execute query; SQL [select domain0_.Region as col_0_0_,
>   abs(datediff(?, domain0_.EndDate)) as col_1_0_ from location domain0_
>   where domain0_.EmployeeId=? order by resultDiff];
>
> nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query

Comment: `from location domain0_ ` what's meaning of this ?

Comment: I guess, you cannot use alias name in `order by` clause, please check.

Comment: First of all see in logs what SQL query hits database.

Comment: show your hibernate.cfg.xml certainly problem is there

Comment: Thanks Sridhar.It was the order by clause which threw the exception..:)